# How to determine program memory space and dynamic library space in linux?

Tags: linux

Recently I am looking into the memory organization of application memory space. I know that normally a program has several segments like .text,.data, .bss, etc. Shared library could mapped to different locations with -fPIC. Is there a specific range of memory space where the application code and shared library could mapped? I want to distinguish user code and shared library code from there memory addresses.